# How much async/await is OK?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

In our project we are using async/await for almost 3 purposes (for all of their methods):

1. Data access layer: where fetching/updating databases (using Dapper).
2. Cache (Redis): read/write.
3. ASP.Net MVC 5 controllers.

The question is how much async/await is ok. Is it ok to use them even when reading or writing small amount of data? How about cache and controllers?

*Remarks*: the project is a little special and it may have about *50,000 requests per second* for few hours of a day.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? It is impossible to answer this question without seeing any of the code you've written and knowing at least a little bit about your server environment. Are you only using `async/await` for IO? Are you using `ConfigureAwait(false)` where you should? Have you done your profiling and stress testing? *Which specific piece of code are you particularly concerned about*?

Comment: We do set up a few load tests simulating about 10,000 users and saw items queued in IIS8 even for simple scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

According to an article I've read:

> Async/await is great for avoiding blocking while potentially
>   time-consuming work is performed in a .NET application, but there are
>   overheads associated with running an async method
>
> The cost of this is comparatively negligible when the asynchronous
>   work takes a long time, but it’s worth keeping in mind.

Based on what you asked, **even when reading or writing small amount of data?**. It doesnt seem to be a good idea as there are over.

Here is the article: [The overhead of async/await in NET 4.5](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-overhead-of-asyncawait-in-net-4.5/)

And in the article he used a profiler to check the optimization of async/await.

QUOTE:

> Despite this async method being relatively simple, ANTS Performance
>   Profiler shows that it’s caused over 900 framework methods to be run
>   in order to initialize it and the work it does the first time that
>   it’s run.

The question here maybe if you're gonna accept these minimal overheads, and take into consideration that these overheads do pile up into something possibly problematic.

Comment: Bear in mind that in a server scenario, you should still strongly consider `async` for I/O, which is inherently unpredictable. Most async profiling tests assume a 100% responsive backend, so they're really just measuring the async overhead. What I'd love to see is one test that measured that, and then another test that used a 1% timeout failure rate for the backend - then see how `async` stacks up.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is how much async/await is ok. Is it ok to use them even
>   when reading or writing small amount of data? How about cache and
>   controllers?

You should use async/await for I/O bound operations, it doesn't matter if it's a small amount of data. More important is to avoid potentially long running I/O bound operations mainly disk and network calls. Asp.net has limited size of thread pool and these operations may block it. Using asynchronous calls helps your application to scale better and allows to handle more concurrent requests.

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx